# Invalid input string when trying to perform a currency calculation

Tags: c#, selenium

Hello I am getting an invalid input string in my code below and I am unsure how to fix it. What I am simply trying to do is calculate the base price and total discount. The output for the both is £...

For Example:
Base Price £148.00
Discount £20

How do I fix the code below as I am using double.parse and Numberstyles:

```
    public double CalculateBasePriceAndTotalDiscountFromBasket(string basketLocation)
    {
        var basketSummaryContent = _driver.FindElements(CommonPageElements.BasketSummaryContent);
        var totalDiscountValue = _driver.FindElements(CommonPageElements.TotalDiscountValue);

        if (basketLocation.ToLower() == "top")
        {
            string basketSummaryContentText =
                basketSummaryContent[0].FindElement(CommonPageElements.BasePriceValue).Text;

            double basketSummaryPrice = double.Parse(basketSummaryContentText, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);
            double totalDiscount = double.Parse(totalDiscountValue[0].Text, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);

            return basketSummaryPrice - totalDiscount;
        }
        else
        {

            string basketSummaryContentText =
                basketSummaryContent[1].FindElement(CommonPageElements.BasePriceValue).Text;

            double basketSummaryPrice = double.Parse(basketSummaryContentText, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);
            double totalDiscount = double.Parse(totalDiscountValue[1].Text, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);

            return basketSummaryPrice - totalDiscount;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error could only explained by a CultureInfo not valid for the pound currency symbol. You can force the correct culture on your parsing with

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
double basketSummaryPrice = double.Parse(basketSummaryContentText, 
                            NumberStyles.Currency, ci);
double totalDiscount = double.Parse(totalDiscountValue[0].Text, 
                            NumberStyles.Currency, ci);
```

As already said in another answer I also recommend to use the decimal datatype when dealing with currency values. It will give exact results in mathematical operation on these values. Also note that in your context (you could have decimals on these numbers) it is better to use the NumberStyles.Currency to account also for the presence of decimal separator symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol`

```
double.Parse(value, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

I would also recommend using decimal instead of double, since something like 0.01 really can't be accurately stored as a double.